# Emoji's are not rendering by a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, emoji, fastly

A few months back I wrote an [extension](https://github.com/sankhaKarunasekara/rereg-validation-extension) to scan a webpage and extracts a few details from it. The webpage is an application form and users of the extension can select complete or incomplete after examining the details given by the applicant. Once the user clicks on the copy button on the extension it will automatically copy the details extracted by the extension to the clipboard with a pre-arranged templated format.

If the user selected complete, a tick mark will be added to the generated text by the following function. Here is the [github link](https://github.com/sankhaKarunasekara/rereg-validation-extension/blob/e16e22c4c7b538fb7dbe75f1786ae2b098d41b2b/popup.js#L107) to the exact function.

```
if (completedOrIncomplete == "COMPLETE") {
            completedOrIncomplete = completedOrIncomplete + " ✅"
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

The final clipboard text was something like this:
`COMPLETE ✅`

This was working properly until yesterday. Now it's not working.

And it displays a message like this, `COMPLETE âœ…`

I thought this might be due to the "Fastly" CDN outage yesterday(09/06/2021) since it was reported that Twitter Emoji's were not loading due to the outage. Now the issue has been fixed by the "Fastly" but Emoji's are not still loading for some users.

1. What should I do to fix this issue?
2. Should a new release of the extention would fix the issue?
3. If it's in fact this Fastly CDN issue caused this, How could a CDN is related to Emoji loading?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think this would be a Fastly issue at this point, nor do I believe Twitter uses Fastly (although I could be mistaken). Where is your program hosted? You should check the cache headers for that URL and if possible issue a cache purge request.

Comment: It's a standalone chrome extension. So no host. And there are no request made from it to the outside. (no urls). According to this tweet, tweeter does use Fastly for emoji's. https://twitter.com/alexhern/status/1402210515124953088?s=19

Comment: OK good to know. It could be a client-side caching issue (e.g. the browser caches the broken emoji response for a long period of time). If that's the case, and considering an emoji is likely treated as a static asset, it'll probably have a long TTL. UPDATE: I looked at a twitter emoji and it's a URL to an SVG (e.g. https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/2705.svg) but that only has a TTL of 1hr (3600 seconds).

Comment: Thank you for your input. Do you have any suggestions to fix it? It keeps happening. It could be a caching issue. if you remove the extension and re-add it works. But after some time the issue shows up again.